# Force a Django QuerySet to not hit the db?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to improve query performance by use of `prefetch_related` and `select_related`.

My goal is to only make one database query for a particular operation.

Currently the way I'm determining whether I achieved my goal (only make one query) is to watch the database logs. I'd like to that to be easier, and ideally enforce that future changes don't undo my work.

Is there a way I can tell a `QuerySet` to not hit ever the database (raise an exception if it can't fulfill a request from the cache)?

Comment: You can test for the number of queries in your tests using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertNumQueries or https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#django_assert_num_queries

Comment: cool, that's nice!

Comment: if that's the best answer (and I imagine you'd know if it is) I'd happily "accept" it, if you want to make it an answer... even though it's not the specific feature I asked about